# Fazer a adesão ao plano pagseguro preapproval

Tags: api

Atualmente, estou tentando integrar pagamentos recorrentes com pagseguro. Atualmente, a API retorna o ['preApprovalRequest'] ['code']. O problema é que eu não sei onde ou o que eu faço com este código para redirecionar o adicionar o usuário ao plano e redirecioná-los para pagseguro para que eles possam pagar. Com pagamentos únicos, é

```
https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html?code=%s
```

Mas com preapproval a documentação não diz o que você faz uma vez que você começa a resposta de

```
https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pre-approvals/request?email=%s&token=%s
```

Isso retorna

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" codificação = "ISO-8859-1" standalone = "yes"?> <PreApprovalRequest> <code> 123123123EAF123123123 </ code> <date> 2017-03-02T18: 29: 53-03: 00 </ date> </ preApprovalRequest>
```

Com este ['code'] como ou onde posso redirecionar o usuário também para que eles possam pagar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve fazer um POST para o endereço https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request e vai receber uma resposta em XML assim:

```
<preApprovalRequest>
    <code>EA0D70578A8AE68FF4868FB8A500B3D0</code>
    <date>2015-08-14T23:15:27.000-03:00</date>
</preApprovalRequest>
```

Depois disso, salve o `code` acima e redirecione o usuário para https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request.html?code=[CODE_AQUI]